# Accessing ADXL345

Tags: python, hardware, i2c, sensor

I'm trying to access an ADXL345 Accelerometer mounted on a Sparkfun [breakoutboard](http://www.watterott.com/index.php?page=product&info=960) via Python and I2C from a Raspberry B+.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2014/06/raspberry-pi-adxl345-accelerometer.html)

However when trying to check for the sensor with `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` the sensor is only shown sporadically at address 53. Monitoring the I2C bus with the following command: `watch -n 1 sudo i2cdetect -y 1` seems to show a device alternatingly available at addresses 53 and 1d.

According to the info at the chip's manufacturer [website](http://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/input-misc/adxl345) it is possible to switch the chips' address via Pin SD0, but I don't know what that means (eg. what am I supposed to connect there).

So my question is: how can make the ADXL345 deliver information at address 53 permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the website you linked to above, if you connect SDO to ground (or low) it will assign the address 0x53. Attaching SDO to high will assign the sensor the I2C address 0x1D.

```
Configuration
Selectable ADXL34X I2C Device Address:

SDO I2C Address
0   0x53
1   0x1D
```